# MySQL: What is a sample page?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I recently encountered a problem where the `EXPLAIN` plan for a MySQL query had changed dramatically and was negatively impacting query run times. In our efforts to fix the problem, we considered increasing the `innodb_stats_sample_page` from the MySQL default of 8. During my search I've found literature on the pros and cons of doing that, as well as how to choose an optimal value for that variable, but I was unable to find any explanation on *what* a `sample page` actually is.

The purpose of them is clear:

> The MySQL query optimizer uses estimated statistics about key distributions to choose the indexes for an execution plan, based on the relative selectivity of the index. Certain operations cause InnoDB to sample random pages from each index on a table to estimate the cardinality of the index. (This technique is known as random dives.) These operations include the ANALYZE TABLE statement, the SHOW TABLE STATUS statement, and accessing the table for the first time after a restart.

That [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-statistics-estimation.html) doesn't explain what a `sample page` actually is though. So, what exactly *is* a `sample page`?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?  There was a substantive change in this area recently.

Comment: The version is 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> InnoDB stores all records inside a fixed-size unit which is commonly
>   called a "page" (though InnoDB sometimes calls it a "block" instead).
>   Currently all pages are the same size, 16KB.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-page-structure.html

Comment: Follow up question: do you know how it's determined which pages will be used in the sample?

Comment: the doc say "Random"  .. so .. could a be a random access to the internal page list

Comment: To clarify, if I run `ANALYZE TABLE` on my own, twice in a row without any pages changing, can I assume that the exact same pages will be used in both executions, or do I have to pray to RNGesus each time I run it because it's 100% random(ish)?

Comment: no... no pray ..(i hope that prays are for most important things) .  but brain .. the simples  answer is that the cardinaity resolved  is the same .. and the query analyzer / optimezer  work as  is expectable  ..

Answer (score 1):

A page is a memory block in which multiple records (for a single table) are stored, the indexing algorithm can take a random page of the table (i.e. the records stored in any page of the table) to make some assumptions about all the records in the table. So it can guess how useful would be to use a specific index in that table without analyzing each record.

Check [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-page-structure.html) for details about the page/block structure

*Why a random page and not random records?* Because a page is stored in continuous memory which can be accessed in one memory operation, so in a memory operation you can get more than one record.

*How does it determine which page to analyze?* Any page is taken, as there is no specific page which is a better sample than another page.

*Will it always choose the same page if I don't change records in that table?* No, it will not, it will take a different random page each time it tries to sample that table. But if there is no big differences between records, the different sampled pages could lead to the same indexes being used. But if there are big differences (e.g. Initially the table has null for a specific field and then half of it was added with non-null for that field) other index can be used.